# MacBook Pro, Mid-2014, SSD replacement

Tags: macbook-pro, hardware, ssd, repair

I own a MacBook Pro, Mid 2014, and its 256 SSD started facing problems almost 8 months after I bought it.  I've been looking to replace it.

[image]

I've read over at iFixit that you can replace it,

But as I understand that not every SSD is compatible. So I was wondering whether [this Samsung 850 Pro 256GB 2.5-Inch SATA III Internal SSD](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00LMXBOP4) would be compatible?

Comment: If I don't mistake, wasn't the MBP Retina using SATAe?

Comment: Did you buy your MacBook Pro new (or an Apple refurb)? If so and it's only eight months old, it will still be under warranty.

Answer (score 1):

No, that SSD is not compatible with your MacBook Pro, as the form factor is different. Your Mac takes "blade" SSD, while the one on Amazon is the regular old hard drive-like enclosure. Personally, I recommend Intel for SSDs, I've had great luck with them.